# Why can I access a URL from Chrome but not with IE8 on the same PC?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to access a URL from my PC.  Using Chrome and Firefox it works.  Using IE8 and Safari it fails.  In IE I get the standard message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

Both Chrome and IE both use the Internet Options from Windows.

What could be causing this problem?  What can I do to try and diagnose and solve the problem?

Comment: what protocol? is it other than `http`?

Comment: The protocol is https

Comment: Might IE be configured to use a proxy that Chrome isn't?

Comment: Without knowing the website or seeing any diagnostic data, there are a lot of factors.

Comment: @Iszi The proxy configuration in Chrome goes to the Windows Internet Option dialog which is the same one used in IE.

Comment: @surfasb How can I get diagnostic data?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome caches web pages in order to speed up load times.

Visiting "chrome://cache/" will display a list of cached webpages.

I assume Firefox also uses caching.

Reference:

- http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qgdSF5fLTkc

Answer (score 0):

Its related to Trusted sites setting. Go to `Internet Options>Security>Sites` and add your website link to the trusted list.